# Considering the variables to be factors or characters will give a very different clustering result in PAM, cluster package

Tags: r, character, cluster-computing, pam

When I use PAM in cluster package, R, I found something that is very weird to me: using variables as factors or characters would bring totally different results. Here is an example:

aaa is a small subset of my data:

```
aaa <- data.frame(ReplacementStatus=c("Replaced","Replaced","Replaced","Replaced","Replaced","NONE","NONE","NONE","Replaced","Original"),
AssetDescription=c("PACKAGE UNIT","PACKAGE UNIT","PACKAGE UNIT","PACKAGE UNIT","PACKAGE UNIT","HI WALL SPLIT SYSTEM","HI WALL SPLIT SYSTEM","CASSETTE SPLIT SYSTEM","PACKAGE UNIT","PACKAGE UNIT"),
Manufacturer=c("actron air","actron air","actron air","actron air","actron air","mitsubishi","mitsubishi","mitsubishi","actron","apac"),
Model=c("PKY540T-6Q2-LFFT","PKY540T-6Q2-RFFT","PKY540T-6Q2-RFFT","PCG290R-0100","PCG153U-0100","MU-GA25VB","MSH-09NV-A","SUZ-KA71VA2","PCA300S-0100-M246","S32 HP/BH"),
CapacityKW=c(54,54,54,28,16,2.5,3.5,7.1,29,32))
```

When we consider the majority of the variables in aaa as character:

```
> str(aaa)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ReplacementStatus: chr  "Replaced" "Replaced" "Replaced" "Replaced" ...
 $ AssetDescription : Factor w/ 15 levels "AIR HANDLING UNIT",..: 11 11 11 11 11 10 10 6 11 11
 $ Manufacturer     : chr  "actron air" "actron air" "actron air" "actron air" ...
 $ Model            : chr  "PKY540T-6Q2-LFFT" "PKY540T-6Q2-RFFT" "PKY540T-6Q2-RFFT" "PCG290R-0100" ...
 $ CapacityKW       : num  54 54 54 28 16 2.5 3.5 7.1 29 32
```

Then I use my code to run PAM like this:

```
j <- 4
aa <- c()
for (i in 2:j) {
      a <- pam(aaa,i,metric = "gower",diss = F)
      aa[i] <- a$silinfo$avg.width   #the highest, the best
  }
```

I have a lot of warnings like:

```
Warning messages:
1: In data.matrix(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In data.matrix(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In data.matrix(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In data.matrix(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
......
```

Then I use the following code to drawing a line about Silhouette Width, and the picture is as follows:

```
myDrawing <- data.frame(ClusterCount=c(1:j),SilhouetteWidth=aa)
ggplot(myDrawing,aes(x=as.factor(ClusterCount),y=SilhouetteWidth,group=1))+
     geom_line() +
     geom_point() +
     theme(panel.grid = element_line(color = "white"))
```

[image]

However, if I use all those variables as factors:

```
> str(aaa)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ReplacementStatus: Factor w/ 4 levels "Additional","NONE",..: 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 4 3
 $ AssetDescription : Factor w/ 9 levels "BOILER","CAR CARK SAF-1",..: 8 8 8 8 8 7 7 4 8 8
 $ Manufacturer     : Factor w/ 17 levels "actron","actron air",..: 2 2 2 2 2 10 10 10 1 3
 $ Model            : Factor w/ 155 levels "2RMFA43C","38VYX050N",..: 93 94 94 92 89 18 15 146 87 133
 $ CapacityKW       : num  54 54 54 28 16 2.5 3.5 7.1 29 32
```

Then, I use the same code to run PAM, I do not get any warnings. And the picture is like:

[image]

So, it looks like when we take the string variables as factors or characters, we get very different result. Why does this happen, and how can I use PAM correctly?